# CDRstats installation error

Tags: sqlite, debugging

I'm trying to install CDRstats Pusher on a Debian 8.2 Machine with asterisk 11.13 installed. How ever it's always getting me this message while i #Make build:

Installation URL: http://docs.cdr-stats.org/en/latest/installation/install-cdr-pusher.html

Error:

```
root@cdrstats:/opt/app/cdr-pusher# make build
found packages fetch_orm.go (fetch) and insert_gorm.go (main) in archive
found packages fetch_orm.go (fetch) and insert_gorm.go (main) in archive
cp -i cdr-pusher.yaml /etc/cdr-pusher.yaml
cp: overwrite ‘/etc/cdr-pusher.yaml’? y
# _/opt/app/cdr-pusher
./cdr_generator.go:55: undefined: orm.DR_Sqlite
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Comment: This one have no any relation to asterisk nor programming question. I recommend you go superuser and mark it as linux/c++. Or send this question to developer email.

Answer (score 2):

check

```
// For version 1.6
orm.DRMySQL
orm.DRSqlite
orm.DRPostgres

// < 1.6
orm.DR_MySQL
orm.DR_Sqlite
orm.DR_Postgres
```

changes in the file cdr_generator.go line 55

```
orm.RegisterDriver ("sqlite3" orm.DR_Sqlite)
```

by this other=

```
orm.RegisterDriver ("sqlite3" orm.DRSqlite)
```

and then you make build and work